# How to use querySelector for identifying one element which has a class which ends with string?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Lets say that we have a simple element.

```
<div class="background-row"></div>
```

If I want to select the element whose class ends with *-row* I can simply use

```
.querySelector("[class$='-row']")
```

But this is not working anymore if I have other classes for that element.

```
<div class="background-row some_other_class"></div>
```

What is the solution to modify *querySelector* to identify that element which has **at least** one class ends with that string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*=`. It will work, but it will also match:

```
class="-row"
class="someclass-rows"
...
```

```js
const element = document.querySelector("[class*='-row']")
console.log(element)
```

```html
<div class="background-row some_other_class"></div>
```